# Configure error "C compiler cannot create executables"

Tags: configure

I have Linux Mint 17.1 (32bit) installed and am trying to install Comsport (from Sourceforge) which allows Nike+ GPS watch software to run on Linux vs M$.

I have unzipped the folder with the Configure file in it and open Terminal, type in `./configure` and get this within Terminal:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in `/home/ken/Downloads/comsport/comsport-0.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I get the same if I add a `sudo` in front of the `./configure`.

Here is my log file:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by comsport configure 0.1, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = HP-Pavilion-dv8000
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 3.13.0-37-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:30:01 UTC 2014

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2525: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2593: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2604: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2654: result: yes
configure:2795: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2834: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:2847: checking for gawk
configure:2863: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2874: result: gawk
configure:2885: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2907: result: yes
configure:2990: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:2999: result: no
configure:3025: checking for style of include used by make
configure:3053: result: GNU
configure:3123: checking for gcc
configure:3139: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3150: result: gcc
configure:3379: checking for C compiler version
configure:3388: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3399: $? = 0
configure:3388: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-i386/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-i386 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-i386 --with-arch-directory=i386 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 
configure:3399: $? = 0
configure:3388: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3399: $? = 4
configure:3388: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3399: $? = 4
configure:3421: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:3443: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
conftest.c:11:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
configure:3447: $? = 1
configure:3484: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "comsport"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "comsport"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "comsport 0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "comsport"
| #define VERSION "0.1"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <stdio.h>
| int
| main ()
| {
| FILE *f = fopen ("conftest.out", "w");
|  return ferror (f) || fclose (f) != 0;
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3490: error: in `/home/ken/Downloads/comsport/comsport-0.1':
configure:3494: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_libusb_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_libusb_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_libusb_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_libusb_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/ken/Downloads/comsport/comsport-0.1/missing --run aclocal-1.11'
ALL_LINGUAS=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='${SHELL} /home/ken/Downloads/comsport/comsport-0.1/missing --run tar'
AR=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/ken/Downloads/comsport/comsport-0.1/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/ken/Downloads/comsport/comsport-0.1/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/ken/Downloads/comsport/comsport-0.1/missing --run automake-1.11'
AWK='gawk'
CATALOGS=''
CATOBJEXT=''
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DATADIRNAME=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GETTEXT_PACKAGE=''
GMOFILES=''
GMSGFMT=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
INSTOBJEXT=''
INTLLIBS=''
INTLTOOL_CAVES_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_DESKTOP_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_DIRECTORY_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_EXTRACT=''
INTLTOOL_KBD_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_KEYS_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_MERGE=''
INTLTOOL_OAF_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_PERL=''
INTLTOOL_POLICY_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_PONG_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_PROP_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_SCHEMAS_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_SERVER_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_SERVICE_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_SHEET_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_SOUNDLIST_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_THEME_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_UI_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_UPDATE=''
INTLTOOL_XAM_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_XML_NOMERGE_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_XML_RULE=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/ken/Downloads/comsport/comsport-0.1/missing --run makeinfo'
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
MKINSTALLDIRS=''
MSGFMT=''
MSGFMT_OPTS=''
MSGMERGE=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='comsport'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='comsport'
PACKAGE_STRING='comsport 0.1'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='comsport'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='0.1'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
POFILES=''
POSUB=''
PO_IN_DATADIR_FALSE=''
PO_IN_DATADIR_TRUE=''
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
USE_NLS=''
VERSION='0.1'
XGETTEXT=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__quote=''
am__tar='${AMTAR} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='${AMTAR} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/ken/Downloads/comsport/comsport-0.1/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
libusb_CFLAGS=''
libusb_LIBS=''
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
lt_ECHO='echo'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='/bin/mkdir -p'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "comsport"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "comsport"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.1"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "comsport 0.1"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "comsport"
#define VERSION "0.1"

configure: exit 77
```

I am running this from the folder where the code is per the install instructions:

```
./configure  (comsport uses libusb-1.0-0.dev, libusb-dev, libusb++-dev)
make   
make install 

You can use this software doing: comsport -h
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.
Ken

Comment: Have you noticed the error `conftest.c:11:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory`? `configure`'s assessment seems correct. You need to fix your toolchain. Do you have at least `build-essential` installed?

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't run `configure` as root.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/196555/ken and http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/196641/umainer.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Just took care of it--appreciate the assist.

Comment: Celada--Yes I saw that error and some others plus a lot of 'missing' remarks. I got the file from https://sourceforge.net/projects/comsport/ if it helps. I have played off and on with Linux for years but this is on my first dedicated (old XP box) machine with only Mint on it.

My other choice besides this app is to try and install the app within VirtualBox--my next step.

Thanks for your comments and also the headsup on Root running configure.

Ken

Answer (score 3):

The actual error is hidden in the `config.log` file:

```
conftest.c:11:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

This means that you don't have the most rudimentary C headers installed on your system.

To fix this, install the `build-essential` package:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

As others have commented: do not build software as `root` with `sudo`.  The only stage in the process that needs root permissions is the `make install` step *if* you are installing this in a location other than somewhere in your home directory.